# Conflict with spring-boot-auto-configure from parent context

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

Currently I am developing a new part to an existing application. This is a Spring boot servlet (Spring boot 1.5.22) which is deployed as a war file to a tomcat. due to various reasons I have to integrate the existing spring context as parent context. The Problem is that with my new application there are 2 that use spring boot and whoever gets deployed second has problems with the auto configure libraries (both use the same version)

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
```

My servlet is configure like this:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@EnableAsync
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext parentContext = ((SpringCompMgr) ComponentManager.getInstance()).getApplicationContext();
        return application
                .parent(parentContext)
                .sources(MyApplication.class)
                .bannerMode(Banner.Mode.LOG);
    }
}
```

My guess is that the application which is deployed first registers all beans for auto-configure and the second one doesn't expects them in the parent context?
Does someone has an idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Two classes from different classloaders are always different. Where does `parentContext` come from? Is it another WAR file?

Comment: yes, there is something like a core application from which all other inherit. Basically there are a lot of webapplications deployed as WAR but still share a common context.
I know that this is not the best architecture but for now I am not in the position to change it